# Getting Permission Denied while creating JDBC Connection to SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a code which connects to the SQL Server and that snippet works perfectly in my laptop. However, when I run the same code from another machine, an exception is thrown:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host <DB>, port 1433 has failed. 
Error: Permission denied: connect. Please verify the connection properties and check that a SQL Server instance is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String ... ar) throws SQLException {
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://<db>;databaseName=webdatabase;user=<dbuser>;password=<dbpass>";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("<DB Query>");
    System.out.println(rs);
    System.out.println("adsasdasd");
}
```

Comment: check for your port is it on local machine if so you can use, <db>= host:1433, but be sure about port

Comment: Where is SQL server installed ? If its in same machine, does that have the same port allocated.?

Comment: @VinayVeluri No the SQL Server is hosted in some other machine.

Comment: @Manoj No, it is not on local machine.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem was setting a System Property while running the code.

The catch was to introduce this line in code: System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");

Or to pass it in VM option:
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Answer (score 0):

If you have already configured your MS SQL server to listen on TCP/IP traffic, then it could be any of these reasons:

- Firewall is blocking the incoming connection
- SQL SERVER is not running on the host
- The port you have configured is not correct, i.e. its not 1433

If you've validated that the issue doesn't fall into the above categories, then you may try doing this to enable port `1433` for TCP/IP traffic!

- Go to Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008/2012/2014 ->  Configuration Tools
- Click SQL Server Configuration Manager
- Expand SQL Server Network Configuration-> Protocol
- Enable TCP/IP Right box
- Double Click on TCP/IP and go to IP Addresses Tab and add `1433` under TCP port.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The issue was something else.. I have find the solution too. Thanks @N00b

Comment: @N Deepak Prasath, saw your answer. Glad that I could be of some help!